# Change the position of an PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have 2 pictureBoxes on a flowLayout Panel and need move the pictureBox1 to pictureBox2's position and pictureBox2 to pictureBox1's position

EDIT:

I have tried but the pictureBoxes dont move...I have used MessageBox for check the positions..and the positions are right but they dont swap the position(the locations not changed...)

```
     MessageBox.Show("PixBoxMover x " + picBoxMover.Location.X + "y " + picBoxMover.Location.Y);
        MessageBox.Show("picBoxMovendo x " + picBox.Location.X + "y " + picBox.Location.Y);

        Point temp = picBox.Location;

        picBox.Location = picBoxMover.Location;
        picBoxMover.Location = temp;

        MessageBox.Show("PixBoxMover x " + picBoxMover.Location.X + "y " + picBoxMover.Location.Y);
        MessageBox.Show("picBoxMovendo x " + picBox.Location.X + "y " + picBox.Location.Y);
```

Comment: yes...change the position between them...understand me?

Comment: @Nogard It seems OP wants to swap pictureboxes.

Comment: can you swap the contents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the ordering by setting the index of the child control (`pictureBox`) within the container control (`flowLayoutPanel`):

```
var index1 = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.IndexOf(pictureBox1);
var index2 = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.IndexOf(pictureBox2);

flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(pictureBox1, index2);
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(pictureBox2, index1);
```

Comment: I was going to post exactly the same code. Up to variable names :)

Comment: Tried it with lables. Swapping the location didn't work. This did.

Answer (score 3):

For special condition like using a Radiobutton, proceed as followed:

```
 using System.Drawing;

 private void rbtPruef_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbtDePruef.Checked)
        {
            pictureBox2.Location = new Point(112, 80);
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(242, 80);
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox2.Location = new Point(242, 80);
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(112, 80);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function

```
public void SwapLocations(ref Point p1, ref Point p2)
{
    Point temp = p1;
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = temp;
}
```

then call it

```
SwapLocations(pictureBox1.Location, pictureBox2.Location);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Point loc1 = pictureBox1.Location;
Point loc2 = pictureBox2.Location;

pictureBox1.Location = loc2;
pictureBox2.Location = loc1;
```

EDIT:
With one point assignment:

```
Point temp = pictureBox1.Location;

pictureBox1.Location = pictureBox2.Location;
pictureBox2.Location = temp;
```

Comment: you only need to define one point and then set pb1 to the temp var, pb2 to pb1 then temp to pb1

Comment: I have tried this, but the pictureBoxes don't move...Are in the same position

Comment: @Sayse I know, this was just to make it clear and understandable. I'll edit to your comment

Comment: `Point temp = picBox.Location;
         picBox.Location = picBoxMover.Location;
            picBoxMover.Location = temp;`

Comment: if this is the code you've tried out, you should post it as an edit to your original question

Comment: This will not work with flowLayoutPanel!!! Control locations within this panel are not determined by Liocation property

Comment: Oh, you're right, I need to read the question better :). Then I'm wondering why do you need the pictureBoxes to be in a flowLayoutPanel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap their positions just swap their `Location` properties:

```
int tmp_X = p1.Location.X;
int tmp_Y = p1.Location.Y;

p1.Location.X = p2.Location.X;
p1.Location.Y = p2.Location.Y;

p2.Location.X = tmp_X;
p2.Location.Y = tmp_Y;
```

To force visual relocation invoke following command:

```
p1.Invalidate();
p2.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I had also very **big problems** with **moving a PictureBox** in a **certain Interval** I decided to Code a useful function. The function get called every Tick of the Timer. The **Sense** of the function is to ***move a picturebox starting from (0 + Offset) until (end_point_of_movement + Offset)***. Maybe the function is useful for some of you:

```
    private void timer_analytics_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //This function is used to move a PictureBox in a certain Interval inclusive Offset 

         int interval, intervalOffset, xCoo, yCoo, xCooNew;
         interval = 303 - 247;                              //Max min location picture
         intervalOffset = 247;                              //Starting Point of PictureBox
         xCoo = pictureBox_GreenArrow.Location.X;           //get xCoordinate of PictureBox
         xCoo -= intervalOffset;                            //Substract Offset in order to calculate next Point
         yCoo = pictureBox_GreenArrow.Location.Y;           //get yCoordinate of PictureBox
         xCooNew = ((xCoo + 1) % (interval));               //calculate new xCoordinate of PictureBox
                                                            //the inverval runs automatically from 0 to (303-247)

        //set new Point of PictureBox which goes from (0 + intervalOffset) until (interval + intervalOffset)
        pictureBox_GreenArrow.Location = new Point((xCooNew + intervalOffset), yCoo);

    }
```

Once the PictureBox *reaches* it **limit** (interval_value + intervalOffset_value) the PictureBox **start from the beginning again!**

The vars:

- *interval*
- *intervalOffset*

Can be modified to use it for your application!

Regards,
Ricardo